# SQL : How to determine if object in same location for >8 hours

Tags: sql, location, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, latitude-longitude

I want to know if an object has been in the same location for >8 hours.  Any ideas how to derive that from this data sample?  Thx

| ObjectID | DateTime | Lat | Lon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 5/2/2021 12:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 |
| 23 | 5/2/2021 16:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 |
| 23 | 5/2/2021 23:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 |
| 24 | 5/2/2021 12:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 |
| 24 | 5/2/2021 16:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 |
| 24 | 5/2/2021 23:00 | 39.88 | -29.00 |
| 25 | 5/2/2021 12:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 |
| 25 | 5/2/2021 16:00 | 39.88 | -29.00 |
| 25 | 5/2/2021 23:00 | 40.11 | -30.34 |

ObjectID 23 should be returned because it was in the same location >8 hours

ObjectID 24 should not be returned.  It may have been in the same location >8 hours, but based on our data we cannot be sure.

ObjectID 24 should not be returned.  The 12:00 & 23:00 locations are the same, but the object was somewhere else in between (16:00).

Update: This is in Snowflake

Comment: Which database?

Comment: Snowflake, so standard SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat this as a gaps-and-islands problem and then aggregate to find the time where the lat/lon is the same:

```
select objectid, lat, lon
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by objectid order by datetime) as seqnum, 
             row_number() over (partition by objectid, lat, lon order by datetime) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by objectid, lat, lon, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
having max(datetime) > min(datetime) + interval '8 hour';
```

Comment: This worked.  Thanks.
I'd upvote, but I don't have enough reputation.